# I want to 1) get unique names AND 2) strip out vacancy AND 3) alpha sort AND 4) append Last name, first name

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrays

I want to 1) get unique names AND 2) strip out vacancy AND 3) alpha sort AND 4) append Last name, first name.

The names are in Sheet1 and the results are in Sheet2.

I'm using `=SORT(UNIQUE(Sheet1!A3:A), 1, TRUE)` to do steps 1, 2 & 3, and that plops the first names in Sheet2 but I don't know how do step 4: to grab the corresponding last name in Sheet1 and append it to the corresponding first name in Sheet1 and put them in Sheet2.

Comment: Welcome. Please read on [how to write](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask] on this site. Also, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: You should be aware that by choosing to share your spreadsheet, your email address will be unavoidably exposed.

Comment: Here is a test sheet, created via a throwaway account.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MCEJhLVUDmD394xJ4L_SJx7PaDCW-xoktRT1MBkiVSE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your sheet is private. Please change it to public

Comment: You should also be aware that by signing up to stackexchange one's email is also unavoidably exposed to every stranger having access to the account details. And also to the public once the site is compromised. Same as when someone signs up in any site (Facebook, Pinterest, Vimeo, GitHub, myphonebill.com, myinsurance.com, sitexyz.com etc). In any case I think you use a great -and wisely, widely spread- alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`=SORT(UNIQUE(A3:B), 1, TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks. I think I have the sort & unique working fine. I'm stuck on how to drag to corresponding data to the sheet.